# Oracle Archivelog specification does not match any archived log in the repository

Tags: oracle, database-administration, rman

I'm not be able execute any RMAN's command as like as below:

```
RMAN>list archivelog all
RMAN>delete archivelog until time 'sysdate-0'
RMAN>delete archivelog all
RMAN>crosscheck archivelog all
```

for all above command I this error has apeared:

```
released channel: ORA_DISK_1
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=6 device type=DISK
specification does not match any archived log in the repository
```

and this command shows:

```
SELECT * FROM V$RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
    NAME    SPACE_LIMIT SPACE_USED  SPACE_RECLAIMABLE   NUMBER_OF_FILES
1   C:\app\Administrator\recovery_area  21474836480 16781828096 548814848   13
```

Comment: What is the output of "Archive log list;" within SQL*Plus connected as sysdba?

Comment: I have attached an image for your consideration.